# The cause of the PHP error in the role section

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, raw

I have a dynamic page 
The so-called MVC page written in raw PHP 
I set it to display a certain header when the user logs in 
And when not, a special header 
with code:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['role']!==1){?>
html code
<?php }?>
```

But it gives this error

```
Warning: Undefined global variable $_SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\پروژه شخصی\navbar.php on line 2

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\پروژه شخصی\navbar.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined global variable $_SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\پروژه شخصی\index.php on line 62

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\پروژه شخصی\index.php on line 62
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Did you run session_start() earlier in the script? Are sessions enabled in the php config? Have you googled this error message and taken the advice presented?

Comment: no ....................

Comment: You mean the duplicate doesn't answer your question? Or you mean you havent done any of the things i mentioned? In either case, i would ask why not, specifically? Look at the duplicate question. Have you followed the advice and still found a problem? Have you done any other research? We're happy to help people when necessary, but we dislike having to repeat information which already exists and is trivial to search for.

Comment: Good. But in future please do some simple research before resorting to asking for help